# Why QPushButton in pyqt5 is slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I wrote a program that contains some widget and was run very slow. I understood when I use QPushButton in code, it slow my program. 
For example, I wrote this code:

```
import sys,time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win=QWidget()
a=QPushButton('button',win)
t=time.time()
win.show()
print(time.time()-t)
app.exec_()
```

it's output is : 1.838 , but for below code,

```
import sys,time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win=QWidget()
a=QLineEdit('lineedit',win)
t=time.time()
win.show()
print(time.time()-t)
app.exec_()
```

Output is : 0.081998 
How can I solve this problem?

**My System information:**
windows 64bit
Python 3.7.0
PyQt5 Version: 5.12

Comment: I see that both codes are the same. Is it an error when copying? When I execute it, I get: `0.062038421630859375` in Python 3.7.2

Comment: Question edited. yes it was an error in copying. but in my python 3.7.0 running time is 1.87135028

Comment: I recommend publishing information such as the Python version of PyQt5 and what is your OS. I have tested it in Python 3.7.2, PyQt5 5.12 in Linux

Comment: Maybe it's a bug of an old version, have you tried with the latest version of PyQt5?

Comment: i update pyqt to 5.12 in windows, but i get same result,I must run it in another system

Comment: On my machine I get 0.024 for the `QPushButton` and 0.013 for the `QLineEdit`. The `QLineEdit` does seem to be quite faster to draw, however nothing near ~1.9seconds. Does your system have any kind of particular theme enabled?  Maybe the issue is not the Qt library itself but with the style?

Comment: @hpaalm can you check adding >1 of each widget to see if the delay is per-widget, or a one-off initialisation issue.

Comment: @mfitzp I check and figure out it is a initialization issue. for 1> button widget  execution time is 0.062

Comment: @Bakuriu where I change the style?

Comment: Maybe related...  I'm diving down and finding that the first QPushButton shown (as a top level widget anyways) takes 2 to 10 seconds for the `.show()` call.  But only in GitHub Actions on Windows when I haven't RDP'ed into the session.  It applies to Python 3.6/7/8, 32/64, PyQt5/PySide2, 5.14/5.15 (maybe others).  https://github.com/altendky/qtrio/pull/55 and various others.